# Setting Hudson variables from Ant

Tags: ant, hudson

Is it possible to set an Hudson variable from Ant?

I would like to :

1. Declare a VER_NUM variable in Hudson
2. Hudson launch an Ant target
3. ANT set the valueofo VER_NUM
4. Hudson does others tasks
5. Hudson launch an other Ant target passing VER_NUM as parameter
6. Ant use VER_NUM (which has been set by another target and another launch of Ant)

Best regards,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible. Ant has no way of setting an enviromental variable to something else by itself. You could do this with an exec task by setting the variable there via a script, however once the exec task is gone - so is your enviromental variable. I would use a property file or something else more tangible which you can then pass to other scripts.

Comment: Great idea.
Here is a link for those who would use it: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html.
Thanks, Chris